# Correct way to link habtm objects in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two objects: Surveys and Questions.  They are set up in a HABTM relationship such that surveys can have multiple questions and questions can belong to multiple surveys.

I am very new to Ruby on Rails, but have extensive experience with CakePHP. I was wondering what the proper way to relate questions to surveys in rails.

When I am POSTing to "surveys" the controller's `create` method is invoked, and from the scaffolding I created, I am able to create a basic survey object.  What I am trying to do now is pass in an array of `Question_IDs` so that they can be automagically related to each other by the ActiveRecords Association.

here is my migration:

```
class CreateJoinTableQuestionSurvey < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_join_table :questions, :surveys do |t|
      # t.index [:question_id, :survey_id]
      # t.index [:survey_id, :question_id]
    end
  end
end
```

For cakePHP, I would take an approach of going through each element in the array and creating a new `Question_Survey` object, manually assigning the values for the `Question_ID` and `Survey_ID` properties, and saving it to the database.  Is the correct (as the designers intended) way to do it in Rails?  If not, how would you create an object and an association at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://azimuthonline.com/blog/rails-active-record-many-to-many-relationship-using-habtm) step by step procedure will help you to understand. This example is written for rails version <= 3.2. You can also see the [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes)  video tutorial as you are making question & answer(checkboxes may be needed) app.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I checked out the article, and it seems as though there is a small section of code that demonstrated saving convention of the "categories" in that example.  Is it just passing in a category called "category_ids" that is a comma separated list of values? I couldn't find anything written in the API about this.